# Find all positive integers such that $\lfloor{\sqrt{n}\rfloor} \mid n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

How does one <strike>find the no of positive integers such that</strike> find all *possible* numbers such that $$\lfloor{\sqrt{n}\rfloor} \mid n$$

What i did was to subsitute $n=t^{2}$ so that the equation becomes $\lfloor{t\rfloor} \mid t^{2}$ But this means that we want $t^{2} = k \lfloor{t\rfloor}$, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$. I don't really know what to do from here. By the way, this problem is in Apostol.

Comment: There is a gap in the problem: If you look at $n=k^2$ (for $k\mathbb{N}$), then certainly $\sqrt{n}$ is an integer that divide $n$ - hence there are infinite number of such integers $n$.

Comment: @AD: Yes even i gave a thought on that!

Comment: http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A006446

Comment: *By the way, this problem is in Apostol.* To be more specific, it is [Exercise 21 in Chapter 3](http://books.google.com/books?id=Il64dZELHEIC&pg=PA73) in Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I suppose you want to find all *possible* numbers such that $\displaystyle [\sqrt{n}] \mid n$.

Assume $\displaystyle n$ is not a perfect square, then there must be some $\displaystyle k$ such that

$\displaystyle  k^2 < n < (k+1)^2$. We have that $\displaystyle k = [\sqrt{n}]$.

The only numbers in the range $\displaystyle  k^2 < n < (k+1)^2$ which are divisible by $k$ are $\displaystyle k^2+k$ and $\displaystyle k^2+2k$.

Thus the numbers $\displaystyle n$ such that $\displaystyle [\sqrt{n}] \mid n$ are of the form

$\displaystyle k^2, k^2+k, k^2+2k$