# Prove: $\lfloor \sqrt{n!}\rfloor\nmid n!$

Tags: number-theory

$n$ is an integer greater than $7$. How does one go about proving that $\lfloor \sqrt{n!}\rfloor\nmid n!$.

Comment: Relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/6369/73324

Comment: the thing to do is calculate this for $n$ up to something modest such as 20, including factoring of both quantities. The catch is that $n!$ is divisible only by primes no larger than $n,$ and the exponents are entirely predictable.

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12544/

Comment: This would imply Brocard's conjecture, so certainly no proof is yet known.

Comment: The third case where $n! = k(k+1)$ can probably be attacked using abc conjecture, and I would guess it is also open otherwise.

Comment: This is actually weaker than Brocard's Problem. An additional condition $\lfloor \sqrt{n!}\rfloor -1 \nmid n!$ for $n>7$ would be required for Brocard.

Comment: If $n!=k(k+1)$ then one of the factors is even and the other is odd. But for $n>7$, they cannot differ by one because the odd factor will be the product of consecutive odd numbers and the even factor will be the product of consecutive even numbers. So this case is easily out of question.

Comment: @Maazul In that case your question is trivially equivalent to Brocard.  But I'd like to hear the argument for $k(k+1)$, it didn't leap out as obvious to me.

Comment: If you imply that proving this would solve Brocard, then no. For Brocard, it would require in addition to prove that $\lfloor \sqrt{n!} \rfloor - 1 \nmid n!$ for $n>7$.

Comment: @Maazul Then I don't follow your earlier comment.  The condition is equivalent to $n!$ belonging to one of the forms $k^2, k(k+1), k^2-1$.  The first is easily eliminated, the second you claimed to be easy, and the third is Brocard.

Comment: @ErickWong Proof of Brocard would certainly prove the statement in question. However, the converse is not true. You see, even if proven, you have to rule out the additional condition by virtue of Brocard requiring a gap of 2 in the factors.

Comment: @Maazul Brocard's problem concerns the existence of solutions to $n! + 1 = k^2$.  What additional gap requirement are you referring to??

Comment: $n!=k^2-1=(k+1)(k-1)$. If the factors of $n!$ differ by 2, then the equation holds. Conditions $\lfloor \sqrt{n!} \rfloor -1\nmid n!$ and $\lfloor \sqrt{n!} \rfloor \nmid n!$ for $n>7$ are required to be proven otherwise.

Comment: @Maazul You have it backwards, your problem is at least as strong as Brocard.  Suppose Brocard is false, then there is an $n>7$ and $k$ such that $n!=k^2-1$.  Then it is very easy to see that $\lfloor \sqrt{n!}\rfloor = k-1$, which divides $n!$.  So proving your claim requires proving Brocard.

Comment: @ErickWong wrote out the argument in my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the Number of Positive integers such that $\lfloor{\sqrt{n}\rfloor} \mid n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6369/finding-the-number-of-positive-integers-such-that-lfloor-sqrtn-rfloor-mid)

Answer (score 5):

Added: nice argument at [Finding the Number of Positive integers such that $\lfloor{\sqrt{n}\rfloor} \mid n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6369/finding-the-number-of-positive-integers-such-that-lfloor-sqrtn-rfloor-mid)    where all numbers $m$ such that $\lfloor \sqrt m \rfloor | m$ are of the form $m = k^2$ or $m = k^2 + k$ or $m = k^2 + 2 k;$ furthermore, **this is if and only if.**

It is easy to show $n!$ is not a square by Bertrand's. If we could prove the current conjecture, that would be a proof that, for $n \geq 8,$ 
$$ n! \neq k^2 + k $$ and
$$ n! \neq k^2 + 2k.  $$
That is, we would have proved that
$$ 4 n! + 1 \neq 4k^2 + 4k + 1,  $$
$$  n! + 1 \neq k^2 + 2k + 1,  $$
indeed
$$ 4 n! + 1 \neq v^2,  $$
$$  n! + 1 \neq w^2  $$
for $n \geq 8.$
A proof of the current conjecture would include a proof of Brocard. **This conjecture is stronger than Brocard.**  Also [stronger than dirt.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_Me_%28The_Doors_song%29)

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Well, see what can be proven out of this. Interesting for $n=8,$ there is no new prime showing up in "sqrt," rather the exponent of 5 is too large.

```
2  sqrt  1 =   1   fact  2 =  2
3  sqrt  2 =  2  fact  6 =  2 3
4  sqrt  4 =  2^2  fact  24 =  2^3 3
5  sqrt  10 =  2 5  fact  120 =  2^3 3 5
6  sqrt  26 =  2 13  fact  720 =  2^4 3^2 5
7  sqrt  70 =  2 5 7  fact  5040 =  2^4 3^2 5 7
8  sqrt  200 =  2^3 5^2  fact  40320 =  2^7 3^2 5 7
9  sqrt  602 =  2 7 43  fact  362880 =  2^7 3^4 5 7
10  sqrt  1904 =  2^4 7 17  fact  3628800 =  2^8 3^4 5^2 7
11  sqrt  6317 =  6317  fact  39916800 =  2^8 3^4 5^2 7 11
12  sqrt  21886 =  2 31 353  fact  479001600 =  2^10 3^5 5^2 7 11
13  sqrt  78911 =  7 11273  fact  6227020800 =  2^10 3^5 5^2 7 11 13
14  sqrt  295259 =  295259  fact  87178291200 =  2^11 3^5 5^2 7^2 11 13
15  sqrt  1143535 =  5 228707  fact  1307674368000 =  2^11 3^6 5^3 7^2 11 13
16  sqrt  4574143 =  7 31 107 197  fact  20922789888000 =  2^15 3^6 5^3 7^2 11 13
17  sqrt  18859677 =  3 37 131 1297  fact  355687428096000 =  2^15 3^6 5^3 7^2 11 13 17
18  sqrt  80014834 =  2 79 506423  fact  6402373705728000 =  2^16 3^8 5^3 7^2 11 13 17
19  sqrt  348776576 =  2^7 139 19603  fact  121645100408832000 =  2^16 3^8 5^3 7^2 11 13 17 19
20  sqrt  1559776268 =  2^2 139 2805353  fact  2432902008176640000 =  2^18 3^8 5^4 7^2 11 13 17 19
21  sqrt  7147792818 =  2 3^2 19 20899979  fact  51090942171709440000 =  2^18 3^9 5^4 7^3 11 13 17 19
22  sqrt  33526120082 =  2 7 13 184209451  fact  1124000727777607680000 =  2^19 3^9 5^4 7^3 11^2 13 17 19
```

Comment: The anomaly with $n=8$: a consequence of flooring?

Comment: The other case $n! = k^2+k$ was previously asked here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350637/find-the-positive-integer-solutions-of-m-nn1.  It appears the OP's claim that this can be easily eliminated is not credible.

Comment: @ErickWong evidently I answered that one, with information from Guy's book... I remember, getting ready for being a TA, we were told to think of mathematics as another language. This is a case where it seems clearer to write things out in symbols, and where the OP keeps arguing in English, without necessarily having written anything down carefully.

Comment: @ErickWong Thank you for explaining why we cannot rule out the case $n!=k(k+1)$. I can see how this is stronger than Brocard.