# Determine the general number of solutions between consecutive perfect squares of $\left\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor\right | n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My question is as is in the title. My way of trying to solve it was to form the inequality $ 0 \geq (k-2)r + 1 -k $ by saying that $ r^2 > (r-1)^2 + k(r-1) $ for some $k > 0$. The obvious solutions are perfect squares but for integers that aren’t perfect squares I believe there is 2 solutions for n in my inequality $ r^2 > n >(r-1)^2$ but I don’t know how to prove it with my inequality.

Comment: wrote a little program, the $n$ that work seem to be $k^2 - 1,  \; k^2,  \; k^2 + k $  where the last one is the geometric mean of consecutive squares, same as double the triangular numbers.

Comment: @WillJagy FYI, your $k^2-1$ is the same as $(k-1)^2 + 2(k-1)$, so in general the values which work are $k^2$, $k^2+k$ and $k^2+2k$, as indicated in this [answer](/a/6373) to a basically duplicate question. Note the method used there is basically how I also approached solving this myself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all positive integers such that $\lfloor{\sqrt{n}\rfloor} \mid n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6369/find-all-positive-integers-such-that-lfloor-sqrtn-rfloor-mid-n) - found through using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clfloor%5Csqrt%7Bn%7D%5Crfloor%5Cmid%20n%24&p=1). As shown in the [answer](/a/6373) there, with $k=\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor$, the solutions for $n$ are $k^2$, $k^2+k$ and $k^2+2k$, i.e., $2$ solutions for $n$ between consecutive perfect squares, as you surmised. Also, FYI, the ...

Comment: (cont.) Approach0 search also found quite a few other similar questions, e.g., [How many numbers such $n$ are there that $n<100,\lfloor{\sqrt{n}} \rfloor \mid n$](/q/2147129), [How many positive integers $N \le 10^6$ such that $\lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor|N$?](/q/1880037), [Methodical way of finding the number of $n$ such that $\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor\mid n$ and $\lfloor \sqrt{n+1}\rfloor\mid n+1$](/q/4024433), [Simple number theory in one unknown](/q/3799585), [Find the number of $m$ for which holds that $\lfloor{\sqrt m}\rfloor$ divides $m$](/q/1209486), etc. Finally, welcome to Math SE.